# How to link my courses/show.html.erb to the current_course?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating an app that allows users to access different courses on video (each course has its own 4 or 5 videos, and each video has its own page).

I created a `courses_controller` which allows me to index and show the courses stored in the database.

Courses_controller.rb :

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_course, only: [:show]
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
before_filter :authorize , except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @courses = Course.all
end

def show
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end

def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) and User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).active == true
        redirect_to subscriptions_path, :notice => "Vous devez souscrire à un abonnement pour avoir accès a cette page"
    end
end
```

Each course is stored in a seeds.rb file.

`courses/index.html.erb` lists the courses, `courses/show.html.erb` shows the presentation of a specific course. These 2 parts are OK.

How to create a link to the current course from the show.html.erb page?

I mean, if I have "course1" and "course2", the link will redirect "( show.html.erb )course1 presentation" to "( ?.html.erb )course1 first video" and "( show.html.erb )course2 presentation" to "( ?.html.erb )course2 first video", etc.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `current_course` here?

Comment: I mean, if I have "course1" and "course2", the link will redirect "course1 presentation" to "course1 first video" and "course2 presentation" to "course2 first video"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your index you are doing right.

```
def index
  @courses = Course.all
end
```

Now in index view you should have link to show page related to each course.

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <tr>
     ....
     ....
     <td><%= link_to( 'show', course_path(course) ) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

To show all videos related to a course in show page start from first video, You should use kaminari or will paginate. So your show action should look like.

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id]) #if you want to show any detail of course
  @videos = @course.videos.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
end
```

Now you will get first video of course in first show request and on each pagination click. you will see next one.

```
<%= @course.name %>
<%= @videos.first.url %> ##because paginate return array always

## to paginate videos

<%= will_paginate @videos %>
```